# Safely converting untrusted files with Microsoft Word in a web service

Tags: webserver, virus, web-service

I'm made a small web service that gets urls, download them, and convert them for another format. Most of those urls are documents (doc, docs,...). Basically, I'm open them with MS-Word and convert their type.

Another critical assume is that my server will meet, in some day, an infected file within the given urls.

Now, I'm wondering how I'm can secure my machine from infected files attack? How I'm can detect it after it done?

I'm thought to run MS-Word with limited user. Not have success yet... but maybe i'll in the further.

What else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply run a good virus checker against all files on the server?

Also, by default, when accessing Office documents from a network location, Office applications treat them as untrusted so continue with that. You could probably go further and write something to strip any embedded macros but this seems like a lot of effort when the basics are pretty straight-forward. Do you even have any macro enabled Office documents that you use? If not, turn off macros alltogether in Office and then you will be fine apart from the occasional, more sophisticated nastyness you might come across. For that, you need to make sure that your client PC is well protected. Avast or similar along with Microsoft EMET, if you can, configure your client PC to only run whitelisted applications.